# How to set max locked memory in a pod running as non root

Tags: kubernetes, memory, ulimit, mlock

Previously my kubernetes pod was running as root and I was running `ulimit -l <MLOCK_AMOUNT>` in its startup script before starting its main program in foreground. However, I can no more run my pod as root, would you please know how can I set this limit now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to set it per specific `Pod`, the way you did it before, unfortunatelly you need privilege escalation i.e. run your container as root.

As far as I understand you're interested in setting it only per specific `Pod`, not globally, right ? Because it can be done by changing docker configuration on a specific kubernetes node.

This topic has already been raised in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649192/how-do-i-set-ulimit-for-containers-in-kubernetes) and as you may read in [James Brown's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33666728/11714114):

> It appears that you can't currently set a ulimit but it is an open
> issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3595

Answer (score 0):

> 

```
kind: Pod
....
spec:
  containers:
  - name: prc
    image: prc/stable
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "1Gi"
      requests:
        memory: "200Mi"
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not agree, I do not want to set up maximum allocatable memory but maximum locked memory (i.e. prevent use of swap for in-memory data)

Comment: Starting with Kubernetes v1.8.0, the Kubelet will fail to start up if the nodes have swap memory enabled.