# Segmentation fault in a pod running on Graviton ARM64

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, arm64, apt, aws-graviton

I try to do a simple `apt-get install curl` on a pod running on ARM64 (Graviton), I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

All workaround I  found ask to install sudo but i can't , I abviously get seg fault too.

I have only apt available for package management.

I hope somebody found a way to avoid this behavior.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged your question with "kubernetes".  In that environment the stack and memory are limited, and an `apt install` process may be terminated if it reaches that limit.

To increase the limit on memory utilization see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61627518/9252818

Answer (score 0):

`apt install curl -y`
if you are already root, you dont need sudo
segfault can have many reasons, not enough RAM, wrong arm distribution - arm64, armv7, kernel etc.